# When does $f(a),f(f(a)),f(f(f(a)))...$ produce better and better approximations to $x=f(x)$?

Tags: approximation

I tried to approximate the solution to $x=f(x)$ for some given $f$, by guessing $x=a$, then I observed that $x=f(a)$ was an even better approximation, and $x=f(f(a))$ and so on was even better, so why does this method work and for which f, is it sufficient that f is continuous?

Comment: I would also appreciate a different phrasing of this question. You know, for those of us who are easily confused...

Comment: It doesn't always; it depends on the slope of $f(x)$ at the point of solution.  For instance, if $f(x)=x^2$, then this method will give you the fixed point at $x=0$, but not the one at $x=1$.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem) for the standard condition that guarantees this behavior.

Comment: This will happen if $f$ is a contraction (and in other special cases). The iteration can take you away from a fixed point as well as towards one, and it won't find a fixed point if there isn't one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method certainly works if the function is [Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) with Lipschitz constant $L<1$. In general, it is not true.

For example let $f(x)=x+1$, then for any starting value $x_0$, the sequence $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ ($n\geq1$) diverges.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being Lipschitz.

Comment: Isn't your function Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Since there is no reaction for my comment, then -1. ...And who is upvoting this answer?

Comment: @Artem Sorry, I forgot to specify that you must have Lipschitz constant (strictly) less than $1$. Then (the proof of) Banach's fixed point theorem tells you that the sequence of $x_n$'s converges to the (unique) fixed point of the function.